A new(?) center of a plane figure and properties
Take a convex (otherwise it makes no sense at all to ask) figure $F$ in the plane with diameter $d=1$ and find the points $N,W,S,E$ of $F$ with the largest $x$/smallest $y$/smallest $x$/largest $y$ value. Let $P$ be the intersection of the lines $NS$ and $WE$. Let $C$ be the barycenter of $F$. Can $|PC|$ get larger than $1/2$? (How to get $1/2$: Take the unit square with points $(\pm1,\pm1)$ and deplace them slightly by $\epsilon$ such that $N=W=P$. Scale figure to $d=1$.)

How do you define $P$ when, say,  N is not unique?

Gotta love how NWSE here have the opposite orientation of the usual atlases.

@Numeral: I can't - such figures have to be excluded.

$|PC|$ can get arbitrarily large.
